# why sybase index size is much bigger than data itself

Tags: database, indexing, sybase

There is a sybase table, for which the structure is

```
{ col1 int, col2 int, msgdate datetime, msg image, primary_key (col1)}
```

We've create an index on col2. There're almost 4 millions rows in this table. I used the command "sp_spaceused" to check table's size, and find the data itself is around 4GB, while the index_size is almost 40 GB (10 times larger).

How come index consumes so much spaces ? given that the indexes are created on columns with type "int"? I am wondering if it is the column "msg" with type "image" causing the problem , or the command "sp_spaceused" doesn't report correctly the space usage .

Anyone could give an explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar cases before and the reason was always fragmentation.
It happens to datarows tables which have suffered millions of inserts and deletes. Allpages tables (aka APL) seem to behave much better: in our database, allpages tables outnumber datarows' but only datarows have this problem.

I am not suggesting the use of APL instead of datarows for this only reason.

The solution is to reorg the table by running

```
reorg rebuild <TABLE>
```

This is a slow, costly and blocking command, as it physically rearranges the data and the indexes structure. The table cannot be accessed by others while it runs and it requires the dboption "select into/bulkcopy/pllsort". In summary, the kind of task to be run on a weekend. On the good side, it is pretty safe: if it fails, the table will be partially reorganized but still usable.

Since tables like yours tend to degrade again after the reorg, I would suggest planning a scheduled weekly job to reorg tables most in need of.

Comment: may I reorg rebuild directly on an index ?

Comment: An index table can be reorganized by a variant of the above command:

Comment: reorg rebuild <TABLE> <INDEX>  It has some benefits over reorganizing the whole table: faster (but it takes some time if the table is large, and this is large), less blocking and doesn't require dboption "select into/bulkcopy/pllsort".  It is still a heavy operation which may impact running applications, but milder.

Comment: I just try the reorg rebuild on my table, however, it doesn't free the disk usage. With the command "sp_spaceused <table>", I still find the index size is around 100 bigger than the data ...

Comment: I see, it looks like this is due to a singularity of Sybase ASE: disk space for image columns is shown as index space. You may check it with this variant of sp_spaceused using two arguments, the second being an 1 (number one):    sp_spaceused <TABLE>, 1   It will break down space in table "sub-objects", to give them a name.

Comment: I presume you'll find in that sp_spaceused listing a medium sized table, a small index (the real index) and a huge "pseudo-index" whose name is not familiar to you; not the table or index name. This huge thing is what Sybase ASE uses to store image columns data. Since every image column row spends at least one full page (2K, 4K, ... depends on configuration), four million rows with an image column each will require several gigabytes. I overlooked the image column on my first answer.